# C# - Get HTTP Server Message

Tags: c#, http

When typing the IP of my Linksys router (Linksys WRT54GS) in a browser, I get a MessageBox saying

"Please enter Username and Password. Server says: Linksys WRT54GS"

I would like to use this message to identify the device in a C# application I am developing. How do I get that last part "Server says: Linksys WRT54GS" into a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it thanks to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponseheader.aspx

The idea is to catch the WebException and match the response statuscode with HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.

Then you can get what you want with challenge = response.GetResponseHeader("WWW-Authenticate");

Thanks to all who helped

Answer (score 2):

What are you using to make the response?  WebClient?

Anyways, you need to read the response headers from the request.  The header which contains the string you are looking for is:

> "WWW-Authenticate"

and it contains a value similar to this:

> "Basic realm="Linksys E4200""

You need to parse the value and read what comes after the "Basic realm=" part.

Comment: I am usin WebClient. All the responseheaders I get says "401 Unauthorized"

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see this message is because the server likely returned HTTP status code `401 Unauthorized`.  As part of that response, the server should be also sending `WWW-Authenticate:` header, and IIRC for `basic` authentication it provides `realm` for which authentication is to be provided.  `realm` is what you see the browser display in that message. See [more info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Comment: I only get a 401 Unauthorized header when I use WebClient

Comment: @user3296337 You're looking at response line which contains http version, status code, and status line.  response line is usually followed by a few headers (such as server type, content type, possibly content length, etc...)  Take a look at all of response headers...

Comment: I keep getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Exception' occured in system.dll. Message: 401 Unauthorized